# I've been trying to fix numbers gotten from two different inputs into an array of two arrays to look like this ["[13, 4]", "[1, 2, 3, 6, 14]"]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to fix integers, gotten from two different inputs into an array of two arrays, to look like this `["[13, 4]", "[1, 2, 3, 6, 14]"]`

I've tried using `Array.from` but it seems to not give me the result i wish for

```
let inputone = document.getElementById("inputone").value;
let inputtwo = document.getElementById("inputtwo").value;

function ScaleBalancing(inputone, inputtwo) {
    let firstArr = Array.from(inputone);
    let secondArr = Array.from(inputtwo);

    let concatArr = Array.from(inputone + inputtwo);
    console.log(concatArr);


}
ScaleBalancing(inputone, inputtwo);
```

I expect to get

```
["[13, 4]", "[1, 2, 3, 6, 14]"]
```

but this is what i get

```
["1", "3", ",", " ", "4", "1", ",", " ", "2", ",", " ", "3", ",", " ", "6", ",", " ", "1", "4"]
```

Comment: Try `inputone.split(',')` instead. Please add the minimum required HTML to run your code.

Comment: `["[13, 4]", "[1, 2, 3, 6, 14]"]` is an array of strings, not an array of arrays.

Comment: What is supposed to be input? Can you give the corresponding original input values to see what you are after?

Comment: I created two inputs to receive integers, which will then be converted into an array of strings. to give me what looks like this ["[13, 4]", "[1, 2, 3, 6, 14]"]

Comment: Please provide exactly what an input would be like? Would it be "1, 2, 3, 4, 15" or with spaces or with the brackets, or still something else?

Comment: Inputone should take in at most two integers like 2, 4 while inputtwo takes any amount of integers just like this 2, 7, 8, 19. which I was trying to make look like ["[2, 4]", "[2, 7, 8, 19]"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match` and `JSON.stringify`:

```
function ScaleBalancing(str1, str2) {
    let firstArr = (str1.match(/[\d.-]+/g) || []).map(Number);
    let secondArr = (str2.match(/[\d.-]+/g) || []).map(Number);
    let concatArr = [JSON.stringify(firstArr), JSON.stringify(secondArr)];
    console.log(concatArr);
    return concatArr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the stringified arrays in a new array.

```js
function scaleBalancing(...arrays) {
    return arrays.map(a => JSON.stringify(a));
}

console.log(scaleBalancing([13, 4], [1, 2, 3, 6, 14]));
```

Comment: It's not suppose to be an array at first... i created two input to receive integers, which will then be converted into an array of strings

Comment: do you get a string, like `'13, 4'`? or with brackets `'[13, 4]'`?

Comment: Inputone should take in at most two integers like 2, 4 while inputtwo takes any amount of integers just like this 2, 7, 8, 19. which I was trying to make look like ["[2, 4]", "[2, 7, 8, 19]"]

Comment: Rather, I got what looks like ["2", ",", " ", "4", "2", ",", " ", "7", ",", " ", "8", ",", " ", "1", "9"]

Comment: please add the part with html input to the question.